# Getting wrong date string when converting toJSON()

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I am sending some dates from Client Side to Server Side using Kendo Date Picker to WebApi. I am facing an issue when posting dates to WepApi. Getting wrong time at server end.

I have tried this on Chrome Console and getting the following results:

```
new Date("Wed Feb 12 2014 14:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"). toJSON()
"2014-02-12T08:30:00.000Z"      //TIME IS WRONG

new Date("Wed Feb 12 2014 14:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"). toUTCString()
"Wed, 12 Feb 2014 08:30:00 GMT"     //TIME IS WRONG

new Date("Wed Feb 12 2014 14:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"). toISOString()
"2014-02-12T08:30:00.000Z" 

//TIME IS WRONG
```

Comment: What would be the correct time? It seems to convert to GMT.

Comment: correct time is 02:00 PM but its return 08:30

Comment: 8:30am GMT === 2:00pm GMT+0530

Comment: umm... 14:00 is 2:00 PM, not 2:00 AM.

Comment: what to do if i want to convert it to local time string

Comment: Why do you want a local time string?

Comment: because its posting wrong time to server webapi

Comment: Why not send timestamp instead?

Comment: At this point, I strongly suspect that this is a prototypical [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A given API expect dates in a given string format, app fails to provide that format, programmer makes strange assumptions about built-in date functions being wrong.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I am not making any assumptions. i just shared the issue i am facing with `DateTimePicker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Date.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) method [should use](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) the client time zone, if that's what you want:

```
new Date("Wed Feb 12 2014 14:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"). toString()
```

Of course, there are drawbacks:

- The precise format will vary across browsers
- Users from other time zones will send different values

If the API server is not able to parse time zone information, it's unlikely that it'll do the right thing with random formats. You should ask form documentation about the exact format and possibly build it manually.

Comment: `new Date("Wed Feb 12 2014 14:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"). toString()` returning me same date

Comment: no its not,...i tried it on chrome console. Here `same date` means what we are passing to `new Date() ` object

Comment: All you've said is that you don't want UTC dates. You've never mentioned that your output needs to be different from your input. Do you need it to be different in some special way? And what for? (yes, we know, for a web API, but why would an API care about that?)